# Recycle a figure with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, copy

I need to represent **multiple datasets** on the same canvas and then save each one as a figure. The original canvas is an object that contains a **Matplotlib** figure with several axis and subplots.

In order not to create this canvas over and over again on each dataset plot, I'd like to **recycle** it somehow. I mean, keep it in memory and acces to it every time I want.

I have tried this by using `copy.copy()` function but it doesn't work since all plots end up overlapping each other within the same figure.

Here I add a **Minimal Reproducible Code (MRE)** to let me understand better. The canvas example figure has been made by modifying [Matplotlib's dolphin example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/dolphin.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import copy

class Canvas:
    '''Figure example to recycle'''
    def __init__(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
        circle = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', linewidth=3)
        ax.add_patch(circle)
        im = plt.imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)), cmap=plt.cm.plasma,
                        extent=([-0.5,1.5,-0.5,1.5]), alpha=0.6)
        im.set_clip_path(circle)
        self.fig, self.ax = fig, ax

class Plot:
    '''Create a DataFrame and represent its info within a figure'''
    
    def __init__(self):
        '''x and y dataframes for xy coordinates'''
        self.x = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.random(50), B=np.random.random(50), C=np.random.random(50),
                              D=np.random.random(50)), index=np.arange(50))
        self.y = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.random(50), B=np.random.random(50), C=np.random.random(50),
                              D=np.random.random(50)), index=np.arange(50))
        self.Graph = Canvas()
        self.fig, self.ax = self.Graph.fig, self.Graph.ax
                              
    def draw(self):
        '''Plot each column of both dataframes (x and y) into the figure'''
        for i,j in zip(self.x.columns, self.y.columns):
            copy_Graph = copy.copy(self.Graph)                    
            fig, ax = copy_Graph.fig, copy_Graph.ax
            ax.scatter(self.x[i], self.y[j])
            ax.axis('off')
            fig.savefig('{}.png'.format(i))

A = Plot()
A.draw()
```

As can be seen in the output figures, different dataset coexist at the same figure (i.e., `copy()` function did not work), when **each dataset should have one figure**.

[image]

I have also tried `copy.deepcopy()`, but the next **error** is constantly raised:

> NotImplementedError: TransformNode instances can not be copied. Consider using frozen() instead.

Since the canvas creation for each plot last the 20% of the program execution, I think it's necessary to recycle the Diagram figure. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you actually need to recycle the figure rather than just creating a new one? What problem are you trying to solve? If you have a function which works creating a new figure for each dataset, I suspect it would be the cleanest solution. Another option would be to keep the same figure, and just clear the Axes (ax.cla()) and then plot the new dataset on it.

Comment: I need it because there could be plenty datasets and create the figure again spen a lot of time. I have tried using ax.cla() but all the axis that contains the diagram are also deleted.
What I'm trying to do is to retain the diagram figure in memory and go back to it whenever I want without creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the remove method to remove the artists you do not want:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove.html

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Diagram:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        ax.plot_my_complicated_thing

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
D = Diagram(ax)  


for i in dataset:
   artists = []
   artist = ax.plot(dataset)
   artists += [artist]
   artist = ax.scatter(dataset)
   artists += [artist]
   # etc
   fig.savefig(f'figure{i}.png')
   for artist in artists:
      artist.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jody Klymak, I'll try it, alltough I'm seeking for a way of create unique diagrams objects, so as to then I could seek the info I want on a iterative way.

Comment: I’m not sure what that means.  Maybe you should clarify the original question with actual runnable code.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll do that, thanks again @Jody Klymak

Comment: I have already updated my question @Jody Klymak. I think now it's clearer.

Comment: My advice above still is correct.  I no you want to copy anything - I’m not sure what that is supposed to do…